# Query takes almost two seconds but matches only two rows - why isn't the index helping?

Tags: mysql, indexing, mariadb

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `Alarms` (
  `AlarmId` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `DeviceId` BINARY(16) NOT NULL,
  `Code` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `Ended` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `NaturalEnd` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Pinned` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Acknowledged` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `StartedAt` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `EndedAt` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `MarkedForDeletion` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`AlarmId`),
  KEY `Key1` (`Ended`,`Acknowledged`),
  KEY `Key2` (`Pinned`),
  KEY `Key3` (`DeviceId`,`Pinned`),
  KEY `Key4` (`DeviceId`,`StartedAt`,`EndedAt`),
  KEY `Key5` (`DeviceId`,`Ended`,`EndedAt`),
  KEY `Key6` (`MarkedForDeletion`),

  KEY `KeyB` (`MarkedForDeletion`,`DeviceId`,`StartedAt`,`EndedAt`,`Acknowledged`,`Pinned`)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

It currently has about three million rows in it.

Query:

```
SELECT
COUNT(`AlarmId`) AS `n`
FROM `Alarms`
WHERE `StartedAt` < FROM_UNIXTIME(1519101900)
AND (`EndedAt` IS NULL OR `EndedAt` > FROM_UNIXTIME(1519101900))
AND `DeviceId` = UNHEX('00030000000000000000000000000000')
AND `MarkedForDeletion` = FALSE
AND (
     (`Alarms`.`EndedAt` IS NULL AND `Alarms`.`Acknowledged` = FALSE)
  OR ( `Alarms`.`EndedAt` IS NOT NULL AND `Alarms`.`Pinned` = TRUE)
)
```

Query plan:

```
id      select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len ref     rows    Extra
1       SIMPLE  Alarms  range   Key2,Key3,Key4,Key5,Key6,KeyB   KeyB    21              1574778 Using where; Using index
```

Elapsed time: 1,763,222μs

In this particular case the query (correctly) doesn't even match many rows (the result is `n = 2`).

Taking what I learnt from working with index merges (though I still haven't got that right), I tried reorganising the conditions a bit (the original was generated by some C++, based on input conditions, hence the strange operator distribution):

```
SELECT COUNT(`AlarmId`) AS `n`
FROM `Alarms`
WHERE 
(
    `EndedAt` IS NULL
    AND `Acknowledged` = FALSE

    AND `StartedAt` < FROM_UNIXTIME(1519101900)
    AND `MarkedForDeletion` = FALSE
    AND `DeviceId` = UNHEX('00030000000000000000000000000000')
) OR (
    `EndedAt` > FROM_UNIXTIME(1519101900)
    AND `Pinned` = TRUE

    AND `StartedAt` < FROM_UNIXTIME(1519101900)
    AND `MarkedForDeletion` = FALSE
    AND `DeviceId` = UNHEX('00030000000000000000000000000000')
);
```

…but the result is the same.

So why does it take so long? How can I modify it / the indexes to make it work instantly?

Comment: This isn't exactly an answer, but I guess you are missing some indexes ... have a look on how composite indexes works for mysql https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `OR` is notoriously hard to optimize.
- MySQL almost never uses two indexes in a single query.

To avoid both of those, turn `OR` into `UNION`.  Each `SELECT` can use its a different index.  So, build an optimal `INDEX` for each.

Actually, since you are only doing `COUNT`, you may as well evaluate two separate counts and add them.

```
SELECT ( SELECT  COUNT(*)
            FROM  `Alarms`
            WHERE  `EndedAt` IS NULL
              AND  `Acknowledged` = FALSE
              AND  `StartedAt` < FROM_UNIXTIME(1519101900)
              AND  `MarkedForDeletion` = FALSE
              AND  `DeviceId` = UNHEX('00030000000000000000000000000000' )
       ) + 
       ( SELECT  COUNT(*)
            FROM  `Alarms`
            WHERE  `EndedAt` > FROM_UNIXTIME(1519101900)
              AND  `Pinned` = TRUE
              AND  `StartedAt` < FROM_UNIXTIME(1519101900)
              AND  `MarkedForDeletion` = FALSE
              AND  `DeviceId` = UNHEX('00030000000000000000000000000000')
       ) AS `n`;

INDEX(DeviceId, Acknowledged, MarkedForDeletion, EndedAt, StartedAt) -- for first
INDEX(DeviceId, Pinned, MarkedForDeletion, EndedAt, StartedAt) -- for second
INDEX(DeviceId, Pinned, MarkedForDeletion, StartedAt, EndedAt) -- for second
```

Well, that won't work if there is overlap.  So, let's go back to the `UNION` pattern:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) AS `n`
    FROM
    (
        ( SELECT  AlarmId
            FROM  `Alarms`
            WHERE  `EndedAt` IS NULL
              AND  `Acknowledged` = FALSE
              AND  `StartedAt` < FROM_UNIXTIME(1519101900)
              AND  `MarkedForDeletion` = FALSE
              AND  `DeviceId` = UNHEX('00030000000000000000000000000000')  
        )
        UNION DISTINCT
        ( SELECT  AlarmId
            FROM  `Alarms`
            WHERE  `EndedAt` > FROM_UNIXTIME(1519101900)
              AND  `Pinned` = TRUE
              AND  `StartedAt` < FROM_UNIXTIME(1519101900)
              AND  `MarkedForDeletion` = FALSE
              AND  `DeviceId` = UNHEX('00030000000000000000000000000000')
         )
    );
```

Again, add those indexes.

The first few columns in each `INDEX` can be in any order, since they are tested with `=` (or `IS NULL`).  The last one or two are "range" tests.  Only the first range will be used for filtering, but I included the other column so that the index would be "covering".

My formulations *may* be better than "index merge".

Comment: That first index does seem to do a world of good. In fact, currently I'm getting a `sort_union` merge between just that and `Key2` using my original query, and instant results. I'm guessing having all three indexes is worthwhile to account for all eventualities (though I'm a little concerned about storage required?) Will experiment further, particularly as I need to work multi-device conditions into this query too (https://stackoverflow.com/a/49014858/560648 up for review next!) - thanks for your time so far..

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - _Sometimes_ it is advisable to have several indexes (for eventualities).  Yours seems to be such a case.

Comment: I'm probably not going to know for a while whether I've "got it", but things seem "better" ... so let's get an accept going up in this house. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that I was trying to use a range condition halfway through the index.

I added a key on:

```
(`MarkedForDeletion`,`DeviceId`,`Acknowledged`,`Ended`,`StartedAt`)
```

Then rewrote the query to this:

```
SELECT COUNT(`AlarmId`) AS `n`
FROM `Alarms`
WHERE 
(
    `Ended` = FALSE
    AND `Acknowledged` = FALSE

    AND `StartedAt` < FROM_UNIXTIME(1519101900)
    AND `MarkedForDeletion` = FALSE
    AND `DeviceId` = UNHEX('00030000000000000000000000000000')
) OR (
    `EndedAt` > FROM_UNIXTIME(1519101900)
    AND `Pinned` = TRUE

    AND `StartedAt` < FROM_UNIXTIME(1519101900)
    AND `MarkedForDeletion` = FALSE
    AND `DeviceId` = UNHEX('00030000000000000000000000000000')
);
```

Now I get an index merge and the query is instant.

[image: Query plan after fix]