# How should I go about indexing for a query with two range conditions?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, mariadb

Next in the series…

```
CREATE TABLE `Alarms` (
  `AlarmId` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `DeviceId` BINARY(16) NOT NULL,
  `Code` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `Ended` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `NaturalEnd` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Pinned` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Acknowledged` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `StartedAt` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `EndedAt` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `MarkedForDeletion` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`AlarmId`),
  KEY `Key1` (`Ended`,`Acknowledged`),
  KEY `Key2` (`Pinned`),
  KEY `Key3` (`DeviceId`,`Pinned`),
  KEY `Key4` (`DeviceId`,`StartedAt`,`EndedAt`),
  KEY `Key5` (`DeviceId`,`Ended`,`EndedAt`),
  KEY `Key6` (`MarkedForDeletion`,`DeviceId`,`Acknowledged`,`Ended`,`StartedAt`),
  KEY `Key7` (`MarkedForDeletion`,`DeviceId`,`Ended`,`Pinned`,`EndedAt`)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

This query is quite slow when the timestamps are chosen such that many rows are matched:

```
SELECT (((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`StartedAt`)) DIV 900) * 900) AS `Period_TS`,
COUNT(`AlarmId`) AS `n`
FROM `Alarms`
WHERE `StartedAt` >= FROM_UNIXTIME(1518990000)  
AND `StartedAt` <  FROM_UNIXTIME(1518998400) 
AND `DeviceId` IN (
    UNHEX('00030000000000000000000000000000'),
    UNHEX('000300000000000000000000000181cd'),
    UNHEX('000300000000000000000000000e7cf6'),
    UNHEX('000300000000000000000000000e7cf7'),
    UNHEX('000300000000000000000000000f423f')
) AND `MarkedForDeletion` = FALSE
GROUP BY `Period_TS` ASC;
```

I believe that this because I am mixing range conditions on two fields (`DeviceId` and `StartedAt`).

If that's true, what can I do to resolve the problem? Perhaps something to trigger use of an index merge?

[image: Query plan]

Comment: I've never had much call to use them, but have you tried [index hints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html)? (_to force using key4)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IN` is sort of between `=` and a 'range'.  So, I quibble with the title on the Question.  Two ranges is virtually impossible to optimize; an `IN` plus a range has some chance of optimization.

Based on

```
WHERE `StartedAt` >= FROM_UNIXTIME(1518990000)  
AND   `StartedAt` <  FROM_UNIXTIME(1518998400) 
AND `DeviceId` IN (
    UNHEX('00030000000000000000000000000000'),
    UNHEX('000300000000000000000000000181cd'),
    UNHEX('000300000000000000000000000e7cf6'),
    UNHEX('000300000000000000000000000e7cf7'),
    UNHEX('000300000000000000000000000f423f')
) AND `MarkedForDeletion` = FALSE
```

I would provide 2 indexes and let the Optimizer decide which to use:

```
INDEX(MarkedForDeletion, StartedAt, DeviceId)
INDEX(MarkedForDeletion, DeviceId, StartedAt)
```

Some newer versions of MySQL/MariaDB can leapfrog and make use of all 3 columns in the *second* index.  In all versions the first 2 columns of either index makes it a candidate.  The choice may be driven by statistics, and may (or may not) be the 'right' choice.

Since `AlarmId` cannot be `NULL`, use the pattern:  `COUNT(*)`.

After making that change, each of my indexes is "covering", thereby giving an extra boost in performance.

Comment: Just re-ran my query using the first index you provided on https://stackoverflow.com/a/49000336/560648 and it's much faster. Again, I suppose that's partially down to luck as I'm not covering all eventualities with just that one index. Also lol at the irony of now needing "covering index" of mutually cross-referencing Stack Overflow answers...

Comment: Comment as on the other answer

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't support "skip-scan" index operations, so you are probably correct in your diagnosis.  You can try splitting the logic using `union all`:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM ((SELECT a.*
       FROM alarms a
       WHERE MarkedForDeletion = FALSE AND
             DeviceId = UNHEX('00030000000000000000000000000000') AND
             StartedAt >= FROM_UNIXTIME(1518990000) AND
             StartedAt <  FROM_UNIXTIME(1518998400)
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT a.*
       FROM alarms a
       WHERE MarkedForDeletion = FALSE AND
             DeviceId = UNHEX('000300000000000000000000000181cd') AND
             StartedAt >= FROM_UNIXTIME(1518990000) AND
             StartedAt <  FROM_UNIXTIME(1518998400)
      ) UNION ALL
      . . .
     ) a
GROUP BY `Period_TS` ASC;
```

For this query, you want an index where the first three columns are `(MarkedForDeletion, DeviceId, StartedAt)`.

Comment: Promising - "Using index condition; Using where" for each of those unions (and for the record it's taking `Key3`, or `Key4` with a `USE INDEX`, although I did add the new index you suggested and it accepts that with a `USE INDEX` too) - the PRIMARY still ends up taking a good 20s though when 1.5mil rows are matched, even if I remove the `GROUP BY` stuff and slap a `LIMIT 100` on it - maybe what I'm trying to do just isn't feasible. I'm also concerned at how that string of UNIONs scales when adding more and more devices in...

Comment: Weirdly just a basic `SELECT COUNT(AlarmId) AS n FROM Alarms WHERE MarkedForDeletion = FALSE AND DeviceId = UNHEX(...) AND StartedAt >= ... AND StartedAt < ...` is a slow "Using where; Using index" over 1.5mil rows (about 1-2 seconds to run) - I would have thought the new index would make that instant

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit . . . It depends on how many matches there are.  You can also use `count(*)` rather than counting a particular column.

Comment: I guess I was hoping it would just "know" that it had _N_ rows matching those index-satisfied criteria :) `COUNT(*)` and `COUNT(AlarmId)` seem to be giving me identical performance

Comment: Based on the trouble I've been having this week (see my last two questions plus this one!) I think I may need to consider trying to persuade management to hire someone who actually knows what they're doing to come in to work and help me for a few days. :( It's too bad I can't just fax you over :)

Comment: @GordonLinoff - your `SELECT` does not seem to match the user's `SELECT`???