# how useful is this composite index when my query filters on one of its fields using IN or OR?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

Suppose I have a mysql innoDB table Foo with fields a, b, c, local_time and e. Foo has this composite index, named foo_index: (a,b,c,local_time)

Would the following query leverage `foo_index` to filter on local_time?

```
SELECT count(*) AS cnt 
FROM Foo force index(foo_index) 
WHERE (a = '332719' 
  AND b IN ('2', '-3') 
  AND c = '1' 
  AND local_time > '2017-02-20 11:20:30.943' 
  AND e & 1 = '1');
```

My understanding is that foo_index will make the query more efficient by filtering on field a, but I'm not sure how the mysql query optimizer leverages foo_index if the query also has this filter: b IN ('2', '-3')

Comment: you can put an `EXPLAIN` in front of your query and look at the results to get a better idea of what the optimizer is doing. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html

Answer (score 1):

The `IN( )` predicate counts as a **range condition** which has the effect that no subsequent columns in the index will help with filtering or sorting.

In other words, if your foo_index is on columns `(a, b, c, local_time)`, and your conditions are:

```
a = '332719'                           equality condition
b IN ('2', '-3')                       range condition
c = '1'                                equality condition
local_time > '2017-02-20 11:20:30.943' range condition
e & 1 = '1'                            not indexable
```

The columns `a` and `b` in the index will be useful, but the columns `c` and `local_time` can't help.

The index order `(a, c, b)` would be better, because the equality conditions on `a` and `c` would be on the left-most columns in the index.

You might like my presentation [How to Design Indexes, Really](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really), or a video of me giving that talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELR7-RdU9XU

Answer (score 0):

Add these two indexes:

```
INDEX(a, c, b, local_time)
INDEX(a, c, local_time)
```

I just finished explaining why in [*here*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49014858/1766831) .

(`a` and `c` can be swapped.)

To get the slight boost of "covering" by doing all the work in the index:

```
INDEX(a, c, b, local_time, e)
INDEX(a, c, local_time, b, e)
```